# How to Find a Control that is inside DataTemplate & assign Value in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataTemplate which is binded to Grid Group Header Section. There are four TextBlock in DataTemplate from one of TextBlock contains the Grid Header Column Value. Now, I want to Split this TextBlock Value into three and assign this value to other three TextBlock from Code Behind. Is it Possible?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="descriptionHeader">
            <!--<dxg:GroupGridRowContent>
                <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" ></TextBlock>
            </dxg:GroupGridRowContent>-->

            <Border BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1" Width="1300">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Name="txtdescription" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" Height="80">

                        <Image Source=".\Images\description_img.png"  Stretch="None" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                            <TextBlock Name="txtdesc1" Margin="2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="{Binding Path=GlassType,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                            <TextBlock Name="txtdesc2" Margin="2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="{Binding Path=(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[3].Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                            <TextBlock Name="txtdesc3" Margin="2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="{Binding Path=(dxg:RowData.RowData).GroupSummaryData[4].Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"   TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

  <dxg:GridControl Name="grdInfill"  Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassType" AllowEditing="False"   />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassDescription" GroupValueTemplate="{StaticResource descriptionHeader}">
                <!--GroupValueTemplate="{StaticResource descriptionHeader}"-->
                <!--Header="GlassDescription" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.GlassDescription, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassType" AllowEditing="False" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="qty" Header="Quantity" AllowEditing="False" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" /> <!--FieldName="Quantity"-->
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Width" AllowEditing="False" Header="Length"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Height" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Elevation" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Mark" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassTag" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="WallLocation" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="SquareFoot" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Weight" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="UnitCost" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="TotalCost" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="FuelSurcharge" AllowEditing="False"/>

        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True" AutoWidth="True" DetailHeaderContent="True"  ShowIndicator="False" ShowGroupPanel="False"><!--GroupRowTemplate="{StaticResource descriptionHeader}"-->
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>




protected void GetAllInfills()
        {
            List<Infill> infillList = new List<Infill>();
            infillList=BLL.GetAllInfills();
            if (infillList != null)
            {
                grdInfill.ItemsSource = infillList;

                grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["GlassType"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
                grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["GlassDescription"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);

                grdInfill.AutoExpandAllGroups = true;

            }
        }
```

From Above marukup i want to access the TextBlock Control i.e '`txtdescription`' which contains the group header section value of Grid Column `'GlassDescription'` now i want to split this value int to three value i.e txtdescription.Split('*') and assign values to other three textblock i.e txtdesc1,txtdesc2,txtdesc3 that are in DataTemplate from code behind.

Comment: Splitting the DisplayText into three new properties in the code behind and having your TextBlock's bind to them in a normal way is what occurs to me. I don't think you can do the split in XAML alone.

Comment: will you please provide some sample code? to do the mentioned task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you requested a sample, I am providing a sample using ListBox.

<strike>**XAML**</strike>

```
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Border BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1" Width="1300" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                        <TextBlock Name="txtdescription" Text="{Binding DisplayText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" Height="80">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                                <TextBlock Name="txtdesc1" Text="{Binding Path=TextBlock0}"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtdesc2" Text="{Binding Path=TextBlock1}"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtdesc3" Text="{Binding Path=TextBlock2}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
public partial class DataTemplateWindow : Window {
    public DataTemplateWindow() {

        DisplayText = "Some*Text*With*Separators";
        string [] splittedTextArray = DisplayText.Split('*');
        TextBlock0 = splittedTextArray[0];
        TextBlock1 = splittedTextArray[1];
        TextBlock2 = splittedTextArray[2];

        ListBoxItems = new List<string>();
        ListBoxItems.Add("Item 1");

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public string DisplayText { get; set; }

    public string TextBlock0 { get; set; }
    public string TextBlock1 { get; set; }
    public string TextBlock2 { get; set; }

    public List<string> ListBoxItems { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT in response to additional information**

In WPF you can use Element Binding which allows you to access any property of a given element. Since you want to access txtdescription textblock's text property, you will have to use the Element Binding. But you wan't to split that into three TextBlocks. So you will need a converter.

**Use the code below for element binding**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
    <TextBlock Name="txtdesc1" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtdescription, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource splitter}, ConverterParameter=0 }"/>
    <TextBlock Name="txtdesc2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtdescription, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource splitter}, ConverterParameter=1 }"/>
    <TextBlock Name="txtdesc3" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtdescription, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource splitter}, ConverterParameter=2 }"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**And here is the converter code**

```
public class SplitterConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        string combinedString = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(combinedString)) {
            string [] splitArray = combinedString.Split('*');
            int postion = int.Parse(parameter as string);
            switch (postion) {
                case 0:
                    return splitArray[0];
                case 1:
                    return splitArray[1];
                case 2:
                    return splitArray[2];
                default: 
                    return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Finally Include Converter Namespace in xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.DataTemplateWindow"
    xmlns:cv="clr-yourconverterclassnamespace"
    ...
    >
<Window.Resources>
     <cv:SplitterConverter x:Key="splitter" />
</Window.Resources>
....
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and creating sample as i am new to WPF (this is my first program) so not able to undestand the whole thing that u have done cant you modify the existing! IF Possible n you dont mind! Sorry!

Comment: Are you able to display **txtdescription** ?

Comment: yes using <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassDescription" GroupValueTemplate="{StaticResource descriptionHeader}"> in GridControl

Comment: It Says "The name SplitterConverter Does not exist in namespace. 
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    
        xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:XtremeProcurementWPF"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XtremeProcurementWPF" x:Class="XtremeProcurementWPF.ViewInfill"
        Title="ViewInfill" WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
        <cv:SplitterConverter x:Key="splitter" />
        <DataTemplate....x:Key="descriptionHeader">
....
<DataTemplate/>
<Window.Resources>
Any thing wrong?